# Python time stamps in while loops acting strange

Tags: python, loops, raspberry-pi

Im trying to create an anemometer with ultrasound on my raspberry pi 4. I'm really new to python so this is my first attempt. Im getting really frustrated and stuck with my setup. I'm not sure why my code just does not work.

```
print("Sending pulse 1")
GPIO.output(Trig1, True)
time.sleep(0.00001)
GPIO.output(Trig1, False)

while GPIO.input(Echo1)==0:
    start_timeX = time.time()

while GPIO.input(Echo1)==1:
    end_timeX = time.time()
```

The problem I get with this code is, when I `print((end_timeX - start_timeX)*1000)` (convert the difference to seconds) I usually get around 0.3 seconds which is high but reasonable (the distance between Trig1 & Trig2 is around 10CM. The code always runs way faster then this .3 seconds tho. But sometimes, this generates random number (usually around ~22s or some extremely high number in the billions). Because these numbers are so random my guess is the code is just busted and not my wiring.

I'll post the entire python file at the bottom of this post because it could be something else is just weird.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import math
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

Trig1 = 23
Trig2 = 24
Echo1 = 14
Echo2 = 15

print("Testing towers")

GPIO.setup(Trig1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(Trig2, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(Echo1, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(Echo2, GPIO.IN)

sound_time = 0.0095 / 343

def removeSound(speed):
        return speed - sound_time

GPIO.output(Trig1, False)
GPIO.output(Trig2, False)
print("Wainting for sensor")
time.sleep(2)

print("Sending pulse 1")
GPIO.output(Trig1, True)
time.sleep(0.00001)
GPIO.output(Trig1, False)

while GPIO.input(Echo1)==0:
    start_timeX = time.time()

while GPIO.input(Echo1)==1:
    end_timeX = time.time()

timeX = removeSound(end_timeX - start_timeX)

print("Waiting for sensor 2")
time.sleep(2)

print("Sending pulse 2")
GPIO.output(Trig2, True)
time.sleep(0.00001)
GPIO.output(Trig2, False)

while GPIO.input(Echo2)==0:
       start_timeY = time.time()

while GPIO.input(Echo1)==1:
        end_timeY = time.time()

timeY = removeSound(end_timeY - start_timeY)
#timeY = removeSound(0.00037872352600098)

distanceX = timeX * timeX
distanceY = timeY * timeY

print(timeX * 1255, "KM/H")
print(timeY * 1255, "KM/H")

distance = math.sqrt(distanceX + distanceY)

print(distance * 1255, "KM/H")
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: It is *possible* that `start_timeX` and/or `end_timeX` do not get initialized before `timeX` is computed; same thing for `timeY`.

Comment: Wouldn't that give an error that start_timeX and/or end_timeX would be undefined? How could I fix that if it is the case that they are not getting initialized properly, just an if statement?

Comment: `time.time()` is probably calling an OS clock, and OS clocks can be notoriously inaccurate.

Comment: Put `start_timeX = time.time()` before the loop starts.

Comment: Tried before the loop, and get the same weird outcomes. Also tried with datetime timestamps and get the exact same results :(